Google Cloud Database Instance automatically deleting database
I have created a db instance in google cloud console. And I created a database named app,but after some hour it is getting auto deleted. Even I created database again and it is getting deleted.
enter image description hereenter image description here
enter image description here
No longer unwanted deletion

It may be that there is a desired state configuration policy, that is deleting things that are not included in the policy.
May not be exactly your case, but in principle:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-configuration-management
